# How to use #include in TatSu grammar files?

Tags: tatsu

The `#include` pragma with relative path does not work.  With a grammar file containing

```
...
#include :: "secondary.ebnf"
```

and code to compile it

```py
with open("/full/path/to/main.ebnf") as source:
    psr = tatsu.compile(source.read())
```

I'm getting `tatsu.exceptions.ParseError` caused by *No such file or directory '/short/path/secondary.ebnf'*.

Absolute paths work, but relative paths do not - there was always at least one path component missing no matter what was the `os.getcwd()` when running the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with this method of grammar compilation TatSu cannot know the path to the grammar file, yet it uses the `filename` settings when deriving path to the included grammar.  So as to make this approach work, it is necessary that `filename` is provided to the `compile` call like

```py
filename = "/full/path/to/main.ebnf"
with open(filename) as source:
    psr = tatsu.compile(source.read(), filename=filename)
```